# Blank space in the start of the Text in Listview

Tags: java, android, string

Hey, I have a simple list which contains Strings in Arabic, the problem is that some strings get a blank space on the begging of the word, so not all the words are allaigned properly..
Here is a screen shot of what I mean:

[image]

As you can see in the 3rd and 4th line, there is a blank space before the name, and the source of the strings there is no blank space.. Here are the 2 lines that get blank space that are in strings.xml:

```
<item>التاريخ الإسلامي</item>
<item>الحضارة الإسلامية</item>
```

Can anyone tell me why they get blank space?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you printed the item values? You could try to use `trim()` on each value. Just guessing, sorry :/

Comment: @WarrenFaith   Tried that, didnt work :(

Comment: Do you see the space in the logcat? Try to change the text, maybe its based on the position in the list and not the text. Try to add some letter on the right side and see if the space is still on the right side of if its between the item text and the added letter... does the space exists when you look at the list while running the debugger?

Comment: @WarrenFaith   Logcat doesnt display Arabic... If I change the text, no blank space.. only if I copy the text (or re-write it,) even in another position, I still get the blank space.. while debugging , I dont see blank space in the List

Comment: Ok than there is a letter that enforce the space... I would try to remove on letter at a time... maybe you can identify that letter... but I have no idea if we can fix it, when we know the letter... you could than try to work with negative left margin/padding to remove the space... :/ sorry I have no idea anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem that you are doing anything wrong there. Try another font, as this might be a font issue. If that does not work, a workaround I would suggest you to set that text in code in the meantime.

If it is reproducible with several fonts, I believe you should post a bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry